# Disabling X input on startup

Tags: startup, upstart, xinput

I have a cracked touchscreen on my laptop which causes mouse issues so I'm looking to run `xinput disable n` on startup (after x has started) but I'm not too sure how to do this. I've tried creating an upstart job like this:

```
description "Disable touch screen on boot"
start on startup
task
exec xinput disable 10
```

which is saved in `/etc/init/` but that doesn't seem to work. I'm running Kubuntu 16.04. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: 16.04 uses `systemd` instead of `upstart`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Byte Commander stated, Upstart has been replaced by systemd and has been for a while now. I just used the gui tools available in Kubuntu 16.04 to set a script to run at start up.

This is available via `System Settings -> Startup and Shutdown -> Auto Start -> Add Script` and then you just select a script file with the required commands which in my case was `xinput disable n`